# Getting the number value of characters in a word and to do arithmetic operations with the number for encoding

Tags: python, for-loop

I just wanted to know how I can write a python program to encode a word using numbers.

for example : "World"
i want the output to be [w-d]+[o-l]+[r]
where w = 23, d =4 and so on.

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: Hi Joyal, SO does not write code for you; it helps correcting your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most analagous way to do it the way you describe it would be to use two variables left (l) and right (r) that will iterate the string and get their base values using `ord(char) - ord('a') + 1`:

```
my_string = "World"
my_string = my_string.lower()

l = 0
r = len(my_string)-1

total = 0

while (l < r):
    total += (ord(my_string[l]) - ord('a') + 1) - (ord(my_string[r]) - ord('a') + 1)
    r-=1
    l+=1
if l == r:
    total += ord(my_string[l]) - ord('a') + 1
print(total)
```

However, I would question if this is the best way to approach the problem. Is there a simpler ways to phrase this problem? **Also when posting to stack overflow, clearly define you're problem, what steps you've taken, and what your desired output is for the given input.**

See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is that you want to add even positioned letters and subtract odd positioned letters. By letter i mean, it's index in the alphabet.

So simple solution would be iterating to characters in string, getting its index on alphabet, adding to sum if even indexed, subtracting if odd indexed.

```
my_string = "WORLD"
my_string = my_string.lower()
sum = 0
for index in range(0, len(my_string)):
    num = ord(my_string[index])-96
    sum = (sum+num) if(index%2==0) else (sum-num)
print(sum)
```